# Rails complex aggregated queries over join table attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, aggregate-functions

I'm doing rather complex sum calculations over join table attribues (has_many through) with fast increasing sets of data. The main purpose is to display charts and graphs.

But as data grows the queries get slower to perform...

What's the best way to handle this?

The problem i face with using caching (memcached for example) is stale data which again leads to often necessary recomputations and slow response times (note: i'm using ajax with json data to display the charts themselves)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a [database view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) of the data you need and link it to a rails model. In many cases this should increase the performance.

```
class MouseStatistic < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "mouse_statistics_view"
end
```

Comment: I played with the idea, database views are surely one of the fastest solutions, the drawback I see in this solution is database-agnostic sql statements for view creation. Is there a way to generate a non-agnostic migration script to create a view on different db engines?